# Writing to Drawing.Bitmap object instead of a physical file

Tags: c#

I have a graphics library from a third party that has a method which creates a bitmap inside a folder. I want this method to write to a Drawing.Bitmap object instead of a physical file. Can I do this in .net

I am using C# 1.1

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on what the third party library allows.  If you can get the bytes in memory instead of dumping them to a file, then yes, you can do this.

System.Drawing.Bitmap has several constructors that take a Stream, so you could create it from a MemoryStream.  Something like this (rough, untested:)

```
byte[] imgBytes = thirdPartyLibrary.GetImage();

System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(imgBytes);
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the method only allows to write to a file :(

Comment: Well, you could always just dump it to a temp file and then use a FileStream instead of a MemoryStream.  Obviously this would be nowhere near as fast though :/